# React Web App with Production performance issues

Tags: reactjs, performance

This is one of those "it runs fine in my development environment" issue.  An important client is experience slow performance on our React web app (graphql, mobx, and apollo).  Because it tends to happen after a long time of usage (hours), I was wondering if it's a Garbage collection or memory leak problem.

I tried to use the performance capability of Chrome Developer Tools, however, I am having a hard time identifying where the problems are.  The memory usage indeed increases.  It's not particularly helpful showing me to the problem.  It shows that Nodes has increase from 5K to 22K since login, Listeners 1K to 10K and Heap 160MB to 440MB.

I read a number of articles on using the performance tool of Chrome.  They didn't get me any closer to identifying the problem.  Love to hear to advice of the StackOverflow community.  Also would love to hear recommendations of tools and consulting services.

Thank you.

Comment: I would start by looking at the arrays of elements (```.map(v=> <MyComponent/>```) inside react.functions. This is commonplace for such issues.

Comment: I'll try that.  THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

**React Performance Improvement Tips**

1. Using Immutable Data Structures
2. Function/Stateless Components and React.PureComponent
3. Multiple Chunk Files
   4.Using Production Mode Flag in Webpack
   5.Dependency optimization
4. Use React.Fragments to Avoid Additional HTML Element Wrappers
5. Avoid Inline Function Definition in the Render Function.
6. Throttling and Debouncing Event Action in JavaScript
7. Avoid using Index as Key for map
8. Avoiding Props in the Initial States
9. Spreading props on DOM elements
10. Use Reselect in Redux to Avoid Frequent Re-render
11. Avoid Async Initialization in componentWillMount()
12. Memoize React Components
13. CSS Animations Instead of JS Animations
14. Using a CDN
15. Using Web Workers for CPU Extensive Tasks
16. Virtualize Long Lists
17. Analyzing and Optimizing Your Webpack Bundle Bloat
18. Consider Server-side Rendering
19. Enable Gzip Compression on Web Server

Learn more: https://www.codementor.io/blog/react-optimization-5wiwjnf9hj

**Tools to speed up React**

1. Why did you update
2. React developer tools
3. The Chrome DevTools performance timeline

Comment: Thank you the comprehensive list.  Since the performance improved after clearing the cache.  My hunch is the cache and garage collection.  What do you think?  In this case what's the best way to approach?  Thank you!!

Comment: Please check the following articles that might help you: 

Garbage Collection in Redux Applications -> https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/garbage-collection-in-redux-applications

Garbage collection and cache eviction (Apollo Docs) :->
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/garbage-collection/

Redux Performance:-> : https://redux.js.org/faq/performance

Comment: I'll take a look